# How to design connectors when I do not know what the customers want?

Tags: pcb-design, connector, cables, ribbon-cable, interconnect

My PCB needs to export four sets of voltages to our customers' PCBs. Eight pins in total are needed. Eight pins at my side are to be connected with eight pins at customer's pcb side. Our pcb is to be integrated into customers' system. The system will be put into a box and made a lab device. So I guess stable connections are important. Or during device dilivery, the connector may get disconnected.

However, i do not really know what the customers' connectors are.

1. Shall I use 1.27mm spacing or 2.54 spacing? At my side, 1.27mm spacing is preferred, which brings to smaller size of pcb. However, 2.54mm spacing seems more common and is compatible easily with ribbon cables.
2. Shall I use connectors that have directions? Connectors with direction connect more stable. However, the customer has to use the same connector.

I have little experiences designing product. Any advice will be really appreciated!

Comment: I would ask a customer first, then if have no idea I would choose my favourite item and inform the custumer about my decision, not over phone but in writen form. Then if they change their mind, you charge them additional costs.

Comment: We have different customers and we only know one of them closely. It is a product to research organizations.

Comment: I would opt for an unpopulated in-line header with a 2.54mm pitch (as you said, this is the most common). Just have pads, don't worry about what will be populated. Let the customer do that. Just make sure you leave plenty of room around the pads so that the customer can fit whatever 2.54mm pitch connector they decide to use.

Comment: How big is the box?

Comment: The box can be pretty small, say 200mm*30mm*30mm. The smaller the better for our product.

Answer (score 1):

First, ask the customer what they want.  It's going to be a pig to wire up if you opt for one pin ordering, and their board has the pins in a completely different order.

If they don't know or don't care, then decide for yourself.  Pick a connector that's readily available.  If you're worried about connectors coming adrift, pick one that clicks in place.  And make it polarised, or someone will plug the cable in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

1st parameter is the required current on each rail. 1.27mm pitch contact pair might not be able to carry the required contact.
2nd parameter is any requirement present on an existing board. Is there any such requirement? You really need to find those details before starting the design.

Comment: The current is less than 0.1mA so 1.27mm connectors shall be sufficient. Could you explain what you mean by requirements? Connection stability?

Answer (score -1):

Who is the primary stakeholder? Who is paying for the development?

You say you have multiple customers:

> We have different customers and we only know one of them closely.

You also say:

> My PCB needs to export four sets of voltages to our customers' PCBs

So, is one to infer from this that they are all using the same PCB (manufactured by someone)?

If so, then it should be easy to find out what the connector is, just find the PCB Manufacturer and ask them. Or possibly just buy one and reverse engineer it.

If on the other hand one is to infer from your statements that they are all making their own PCBs; then dictate to them what the "standard" will be.